# Button's .click() command not working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, click

I have a button

```
<asp:Button ID="submitRegionsButton" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="OnSubmitRegion" />
```

and when I click it, everything works as expected, however when I have a javascript function call it using btn.click(), the click command is not executed. The button is found properly but just doesn't then work or run the OnClick function in my code behind

Any ideas? It works in IE, haven't tested firefox though

Okay, tested in firefox, doesn't work there. Everything works right up until the actual call to .click(), no idea why :/

Code that calls the click:

```
    function dropDownProductBlur() {
        if (isItemClicked) {
            var combo = $find("<%= productDropDown.ClientID %>");
            var btnSubmitProd = $get(combo.get_id() + "_Footer" + "_submitProductsButton");
            if (btnSubmitProd)
                btnSubmitProd.click();
        }
    }
```

Just for understanding, the button is contained within a dropdown, and when the dropdown closes, it "clicks" the button (or, well, is supposed to..) clicking the button manually works, and the find works and finds the button properly.

Comment: And where is the `.click()` code?

Comment: the button is contained within a dropdown, and when the dropdown closes it runs the .click() on the button within it, i'll put the code that runs on dropdownclose

Comment: might be a dumb comment but: you have: `OnClick="OnSubmitRegion"` but i dont see it in the function aback. so are you sure you're calling the right one?

Comment: Yeah I am, like I said the same button works perfectly when manually clicking it, just some oddity with trying to click it from clientside code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem myself.  I believe the issue is that in javascript, this .click() is either treated as the component's onClientClick event, or something else entirely.  Not sure on this.

In any case, my solution:
Instead of calling btnSubmitProd.click(), do `__doPostBack('Foo', 'Bar');` where Foo is an arbitrary name (typically the component, so "submitRegionButton") and Bar is an arbitrary value for that name, typically the event (so "click") (also, there are TWO underscores there, not one).  Then, in your codebehind:

```
try {
  if (Request["__EVENTTARGET".ToString() == "Foo" && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString() == "Bar" {
    //call the codebehind directly here
    OnSubmitRegion(null null);
  }
}
```

I assume your codebehind function is of the form `protected void OnSubmitRegion(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  If you need the values for any of those variables, things get a little more complicated.  If not, give the above a try.

Comment: Seems to work, the 'Foo' and 'Bar' weren't what appeared for the respective requests but I was able to figure them out so thanks :)

Comment: Ignore my previous comment!! I was accidentally auto-postbacking so what you said was correct, i was just seeing the first of two postbacks and it was wrong/different, thanks!!