# asp.net button - JS click does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, click

I am trying to call from JS to C# function. I can not use ajax. I have tried to create a ASP.NET button when it clicked it calls the C# function and call the click function from JS:

On HTML:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
```

JS:

```
alert("Before CLICK");
document.getElementById("UploadButton").click();
alert("After CLICK");
```

ASP.NET:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CODE
}
```

The problem is that the click event from JS does not working. I have tried to write after the first line of the JS code an alert to see if the code rich to that line but I can only see `"After CLICK"`.

I have seen this answer: [Button's .click() command not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066672/buttons-click-command-not-working-in-chrome) But I did not quite get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `ClientIDMode` to `Static`

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
```

Otherwise, it will have some randomized id, generated by ASP.NET, setting the CLientIDMode to Static, you're saying ASP.NET not to meddle with your ids and keep them intact.

Other option would be to use the `ClientID` property which will have the value of the automatically generated id like

```
document.getElementById('<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

In ASP.net When Page Renders it Will change it somthing like `'containerName...YourButtonName'`
So Using `ClientID` you will get actual ID of Button.

```
document.getElementById('#<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>').click();
```

Or You can Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` which will rendered same ID what you wrote in Your `.aspx`

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton"
 ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
```